# Call method in ListView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a simple ListView with an EmptyDataTemplate. In the EmptyDataTemplate, there is a LinkButton whose Visble property value is an expression that calls a method in my code behind. The problem is that the LinkButton is always visible regardless of whether the method returns true or false (my method isn't being called as I even set a breakpoint on it). Anyone come across this? What's happening here?

e.g.

```
<asp:ListView ID="peopleListView" runat="server" ...>
   ...
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Sorry, no people to view.<br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="newButton" runat="server" Visible='<%# EditPermitted() %>'>New Record</asp:LinkButton>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the code behind, I have the method:

```
protected bool EditPermitted()
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can put scriplets `<% %>` inside of server controls.

You need to grab the RowDataBound event, and set the link button's visibility there

```
void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow) {
        LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("newButton");
        lb.Visible = EditPErmitted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response. When I wrap the method call in Eval(...) I get the following error at runtime: Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Hmm, when I try using the style attribute like you showed, the HTML that gets rendered out for the LinkButton is: `<a id="MainContent_peopleListView_newButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$peopleListView$ctrl0$newButton&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:<%= EditPermitted() ? "block" : "none" %>">New Record</a>` It doesn't seem to be evaluating the expression in <%= %>, but just spitting it out verbatim..

Comment: @user1150762 - put a back tick around the html so I can see it.   `

Comment: This is what is in the aspx markup that caused the previous html to be renderedout:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="newButton" runat="server" style='display:<%= EditPermitted() ? "block" : "none"  %>'>New Record</asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: @user1150762 - thanks for your patience - I think I finally realized what the problem was.  See my edit

Comment: Thanks Adam, that worked great. Another thing I just successfully tried based on your advice was to move the expression outside of the server side LinkButton control like:

`<EmptyDataTemplate>
            Sorry, no people to view.<br />
            <% if (EditPermitted()) { %>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="newButton" runat="server">New Record</asp:LinkButton>
            <% } %>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use code blocks like `<% ... %>` or `<%= ... %>` inside the **attributes** of server controls. Only data binding blocks like `<%# ... %>`. But you can use code blocks inside your EmptyDataTemplate, in this case a simple if statement should work:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
  <% if(EditPermitted()) { %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="newButton" runat="server" ... />
  <% } %>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```